# HSQ Hibernate Update Problem

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

I am trying to update an object but hibernate is trying to insert the object newly in the database, as a result i am getting a violation error since the object already exist in database.

for e.g.

```
    Category X= getCategory();//returns me a category which i then update  
    Transaction tx = null;
    try
    {
        tx=session.beginTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        session.Update(X);
        tx.commit();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

I am getting this error because the category already exist in the database

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

I through by using session.update, hibernate automatically update the object. Does anyone know how to update without writing sql??

Full error:

```
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into CATEGORY (CATEGORYNAME, PARENT_CATEGORY_ID, CATEGORYID) values (?, ?, ?)
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2395)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2858)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
    at com.BiddingSystem.server.ServiceImpl.TestSaveCategory(ServiceImpl.java:280)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at net.sf.gilead.gwt.PersistentRemoteService.processCall(PersistentRemoteService.java:174)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:243)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into CATEGORY (CATEGORYNAME, PARENT_CATEGORY_ID, CATEGORYID) values ('Laptop', '0', '397') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2598)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:407)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2737)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: By the way, I wanted to know one more thing. Is there any tool that can generate mapping file 100 % accurately without having the need to go and edit these mapping file  because I am new to hibernate and for now, I don't have too much to be able to master the mapping file, so any best tools in your thoughts. Thanks

Comment: If you use Hibernate 3, then the mapping file is generated with the help of Annotations that you supply in the POJO

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing what `getCategory()` does it's hard to answer your question.  According to the hibernate docs, Session.update expects to be passed a *detached* entity, which is an entity that was returned by Session.load() or Session.get() from a previous session that has been closed.

It turns out that in normal hibernate usage, update is rarely needed.  This is because hibernate can detect changes to objects automatically.  Here is a more common pattern:

```
    Transaction tx = null;
    try
    {
        tx=session.beginTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        Category X = session.load(Category.class,[categoryId])
        X.setXXX(...) // update the category
        tx.commit();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

Upon commit, hibernate will know that the category returned from Load was modified and will automatically issue an update to the database.

Stated more formally, hibernate will automatically detect changes made to a *persistent* entities, and automatically issue an UPDATE when the transaction is committed.  A persistent entity is any entity returned from Session.get, Session.load, or any of the session query functions.

More information on persistent, detached and transient objects can be found here

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview